# Show cart and chekout in the header woocomerece

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi all maybe someone is aware on how to add cart page and checkout page content into the header.php so it shows on every page? tried looking but haven't found a proper answer. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you referring to minicart?

Comment: no the whole cart and chekout as original

Comment: This is not possible. It may expose your site to security vulnerabilities. You should try using mini cart widget instead. - It is suggested way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, the below code may help you**

```
      <?php 
        global $woocommerce;
        $qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); 
        $total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
        $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        echo $loginout = wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false ); // show wp dynamic login / logout link
     ?>

           <a href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url() ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Checkout' ) ?>">
               <?php _e( 'Checkout' ) ?>
            </a> |
           <a href="<?php echo $cart_url ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Cart' ) ?>">
               <?php _e( 'Cart ( '. $qty .' ) -'. $total ) ?>
           </a>
```

Comment: i pasted your code but no errors and nothing shows up, any tips ? to make it more clear i would like to put the whole checkout and cart content into header, not minified or anything like that

Comment: it displays the links, after clicking on them i get redirected, but what i need is to display the whole content that would appear when you go on the cart page or checkout let me know if thats more clear, cheers!

Comment: Whole content means, what type of content (relates to cart & checkout) you want to show on header instead of links. Could you please explain more..

Comment: The whole page content, everything you would see when you go on cart or chekout pages. Any clearer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145014/discussion-between-vijayalakshmi-and-zygimantas-kairys).

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a single piece of code ;)

A free [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-floating-minicart/) is already available in Wordpress and it will let you add minicart as a widget to any of your sidebar (here in top bar).